# Nested json arrays inside select over 4 tables

Tags: postgresql

I have 4 tables, one related to another.
The schema looks like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA vehicles;

CREATE TABLE vehicles.car (
    id serial,
    name text,
    description text,

  CONSTRAINT car_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE vehicles.car_door (
     id serial,
    name text,    
    car_id serial,

  CONSTRAINT car_door_pk PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT car_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (car_id) REFERENCES vehicles.car(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE vehicles.car_door_handle (
   id serial,
    name text,
   car_door_id serial,

  CONSTRAINT car_door_handle_pk PRIMARY KEY(id),
   CONSTRAINT car_door_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (car_door_id) REFERENCES vehicles.car_door(id) ON DELETE     CASCADE

);

CREATE TABLE vehicles.car_door_handle_screw(
    id serial,
    name text,
    car_door_handle_id serial,

  CONSTRAINT  car_door_handle_screw_pk PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT car_door_handle_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (car_door_handle_id) REFERENCES     vehicles.car_door_handle(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


INSERT INTO vehicles.car (name) VALUES ('car 1');
INSERT INTO vehicles.car (name) VALUES ('car 2');
INSERT INTO vehicles.car (name) VALUES ('car 3');
INSERT INTO vehicles.car (name) VALUES ('car 4');

INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door (name, car_id ) VALUES ('car door 1', 1);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door (name, car_id ) VALUES ('car door 2', 1);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door (name, car_id ) VALUES ('car door 3', 2);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door (name, car_id ) VALUES ('car door 4', 3);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door (name, car_id ) VALUES ('car door 6', 4);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door (name, car_id ) VALUES ('car door 7', 4);

INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle (name, car_door_id ) VALUES ('car door handle 1', 1);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle (name, car_door_id ) VALUES ('car door handle 2', 1);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle (name, car_door_id ) VALUES ('car door handle 3', 2);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle (name, car_door_id ) VALUES ('car door handle 4', 2);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle (name, car_door_id ) VALUES ('car door handle 5', 2);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle (name, car_door_id ) VALUES ('car door handle 6', 3);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle (name, car_door_id ) VALUES ('car door handle 7', 4);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle (name, car_door_id ) VALUES ('car door handle 8', 5);


INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle_screw (name, car_door_handle_id ) VALUES ('car handle screw 1',     1);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle_screw (name, car_door_handle_id ) VALUES ('car handle screw 2', 1);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle_screw (name, car_door_handle_id ) VALUES ('car handle screw 3',  2);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle_screw (name, car_door_handle_id ) VALUES ('car handle screw 4', 2);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle_screw (name, car_door_handle_id ) VALUES ('car handle screw 5', 3);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle_screw (name, car_door_handle_id ) VALUES ('car handle screw 6', 4);
INSERT INTO vehicles.car_door_handle_screw (name, car_door_handle_id ) VALUES ('car handle screw 7', 5);
```

Now I would like to create a single select statement that would utilise tools like jsonb_agg to return all nested data all the way deep from car to car handle.

I already have a query that nests car_doors inside cars:

```
select pt.id , pt.name,   jsonb_agg(row_to_json(tlt.*)::jsonb -     'car_id') as     car_doors from vehicles.car pt JOIN vehicles.car_door tlt ON pt.id=tlt.car_id GROUP BY pt.id,     pt.name;
```

I need to upgrade this query so that all the tables are includes. Any help appreciated. Thanks
Here is db-fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8JVTZNvHaMYx7erwDyWARB/4

I tried a simple 1-level nested query and it worked fine. I need to extend the depth of the query all the way down to car_door_handle_screw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it from the inside outward using the following pattern:

```
with cdh_screw_j as (
  select car_door_handle_id, to_jsonb(t) as car_door_handle_screw
    from vehicles.car_door_handle_screw t
), cd_handle_raw as (
  select cdh.id, cdh.car_door_id, cdh.name, jsonb_agg(cdhs.car_door_handle_screw) as car_door_handle_screws
    from vehicles.car_door_handle cdh
         left join cdh_screw_j cdhs on cdhs.car_door_handle_id = cdh.id
   group by cdh.id, cdh.car_door_id, cdh.name
), cd_handle_j as (
  select car_door_id, to_jsonb(t) as car_door_handle
    from cd_handle_raw t
), c_door_raw as (
  select cd.id, cd.name, cd.car_id, jsonb_agg(cdh.car_door_handle) as car_door_handles
    from vehicles.car_door cd
         left join cd_handle_j cdh on cdh.car_door_id = cd.id
   group by cd.id, cd.name, cd.car_id
), c_door_j as (
  select car_id, to_jsonb(t) as car_door
    from c_door_raw t
), car_raw as (
  select c.id, c.name, c.description, jsonb_agg(cd.car_door) as car_doors
    from vehicles.car c
         left join c_door_j cd on cd.car_id = c.id
   group by c.id, c.name, c.description
)
select to_jsonb(car_raw) as result
  from car_raw;
```

Updated [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8JVTZNvHaMYx7erwDyWARB/4)

Comment: I like this anwser, so I gave it a thumbs up. Thanks.